# Changing directory of PHP backup

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a script for database backing up in PHP. It's working now. My question is how do I change the directory of my backups?

**This is the code:**

```
<form action = '' method = 'POST'>
<input type = 'submit' name = "backup" value="Backup">              
</form>

<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = ' ';
    $dbname = 'itravel';
    $backup_name = "mybackup.sql";
    if(isset($_POST['backup']))
    {
    $backup = "c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --opt -h $host -u $user $dbname > $backup_name";
    system($backup);
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is the exact problem? does `$_POST['backup']` contain what you need?

Comment: i only want to change the location of the saved backups. but i dont know how

Comment: @k102 it looks like that contains "Backup" the value of which isn't being used in his script?

Comment: Maybe using full path in `$backup_name = "PATH_TO_BKP/mybackup.sql";` could help you?

Comment: it's working now i just included a path inside the $backup. thank you anyway :)

Comment: i added this code $path = "/xampp/htdocs/itravel/admin/backup";
$backup = "c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --opt -h $host -u $user $dbname > $path/$backup_name";

Answer (score 2):

At the moment your sql backup output is going to `mybackup.sql` which is set in the line

> $backup_name = "mybackup.sql";

Try changing this value to change the output location of your backup. So something like:

> $backup_name = "~/mydbbackups/mybackup.sql";

(depends on your host OS really)